# My app lost connection when I try play a sound using audioplayers

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter and whenever I want to to play a sound it crashes and throw me this:

```
iOS => call startHeadlessService, playerId d580eb03-1cab-4a44-9b7d-5b80ac32a53c
iOS => call play, playerId d580eb03-1cab-4a44-9b7d-5b80ac32a53c
play!
Lost connection to device.
```

I don't know why, I followed step by step.
Here's the code I write if it's helping:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioCache();
                player.play('note1.wav');
              },
              child: Text('Play me!'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And Here is my pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  audioplayers: ^0.16.0
```

I've done everthing that was in that course step by step, but instead of asking me to allow microphones ( that was in course ), the app just lost connection.
I don't know why, in the course never explain what to do if you meet errors.

Can you help me understand why is this happening and how can be handled? It would help me a lot. Thank you in advance!

The emulator is iPhone 11 pro max.
Also I tried running it by calling " flutter run " in the terminal

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean`? If that doesn't work, try uninstalling the app from the device and running it again

Comment: Yes I did ' flutter clean ', let me uninstall and run it again

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: It's just launching and then stopping before anything appears?

Comment: Its launching, I click that button then it stops

Comment: you have the 'note1.wav' file in an 'assets' (or similar) folder and reference it in pubspec? Also, did you have to update your plist file for permissions?

Comment: Yes I do have all the files in a folder name assets. I don't know anything about plist file for permissions, in the course we didn't do that

Comment: Is the folder named 'assets' or 'Assets'? I believe audioCache prefixes it for 'assets' -- also, for debugging sake, if you comment out `player.play('note1.wav');` and click the button, does it still crash?

Comment: No it doesn't crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220798/discussion-between-j-saw-and-calin-onaca).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of J. Saw from the comments above, we changed the package version from 0.16 to 0.10 and it's working